# symfony/Routing - import yml resource twice

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm trying to enable optional locale placeholder for all the routes without duplicating everything. My routes look like this:

```
site:
    prefix: /
    resource: "routes-site.yml"

site_i18n:
    prefix: /{_locale}
    resource: "routes-site.yml"
    defaults: {_locale: pl}
    requirements:
        _locale: 'en'
```

But I get only site_i18n working. Why I cannot import same resource multiple times?
It's Symfony 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the routes have same route name, the later import overrides routes from the first one.
Have a look at: [BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle). It allows you even localize the whole path, but in this case, you will just need localize prefix.

Comment: Adding separate bundle for this is far too expensive for me. I'm looking for build-in solution.

Comment: What do you mean by expensive? Loading one more (well written) bundle has minimal (almost none) performance impact. It actually comes down to when you use the bundle - during loading routes, which are cached then. It actually only adds custom route loading.

Comment: Any extra code costs time (while generating urls for example). But maybe there is no better solution in this case. I will look at the source code then.

Comment: You can now add `name_prefix: en_` to the second import and it will work. But this still creates 2 sets of routes, so linking inside the app becomes more difficult.